# FreeForm Pro iOs file size too large, how to allow larger images or constrain/resize

Tags: solspace-freeform, file-uploads, image, uploads

EE 5.3.0
FreeForm 1.8.1

I am using FreeForm Pro to handle forms. I have users saying they are unable to upload images from their iPhone because they keep getting errors that say

```
* File size too large
* Could not upload file
```

I get the same result from my iPhone.

I have tried increasing the max file size in the field settings in FreeForm to 10,000 KB and have also tried to apply an image manipulation in the directory like so

[image]

Neither of these seem to be working and I keep getting the same error.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you checked your php max upload filesize?

Comment: It looks like it is currently set to 2M. Is this a php.ini change? I've looked into how to do this with my host provider HostGator but am hesitant since I'm not used to messing with php.ini settings directly.

Comment: Don't HG use Cpanel? If they do look for MultiPHP INI editor, you can safely change various values in there.

Comment: I ended up calling contacting their support line and they changed it for me, which fixed the problem. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

How big is your photo from your iPhone ?   It's maybe larger than 10megs each ?

Comment: it is 1.8 mb. I wonder if it might be the file type as I've been hearing that iOs saves files as a different type.